# using option with php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is my table subjects in lecturer database

```
No  subject  credit_hour
1  (111) AAA     4
2  (222) BBB     3
3  (222) CCC     4
4  (333) DDD     3
```

This is what I have done using ajax

This is my testing1.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
mysql_select_db('lecturer');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str==="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","testing3.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="subjects" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a subject:</option>  
<?php $result= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM subjects'); ?>
    <?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $list=array($row['subject'],$row['credit_hour']);
        ?>

    <option>
          <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['subject'] ); ?>
          <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['credit_hour'] ); ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>subject info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my testing3.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','lecturer');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"lecturer");
$sql="SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE No = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Credit_hour</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['credit_hour'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The problem is that when I select (111)AAA 4
it should be appearing a table which is located in testing3.php
but it did't fetch any data in the table

Thank you

Comment: you need to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

After your first select query you should put the `subject, hour_credit` pair in an array, then on `onchange` event of the first `option`(your subject list) you should check which index is selected then set the second `options` selected index.